# Creating a turtle program that does commands based upon the button pressed

Tags: python, command, turtle-graphics

I haven't been able to find anything online for this but I need to create a program that:

- If the left button is pressed, the turtle should move to that location and draw a small square.
- If the right button is pressed, the turtle should move that that location and draw a small circle.
- If the middle button is pressed, the turtle should change to a different random color.
- You should also change the color if the use presses the space bar.

Any suggestions on how to start?

Here is some code I have tried so far:

```
def k2(x,y): turtle.penup() turtle.setposition(x,y) turtle.pendown() turtle.circle(radius)
```

This is the top from turtle

```
import * setup(500, 500) Screen() title("Turtle Keys") move = Turtle() showturtle()
```

This is the bottom

```
onkey(k1, "Up") onkey(k2, "Left") onkey(k3, "Right") onkey(k4, "Down") listen() mainloop()
```

Comment: please show some code you have tried so far

Comment: def k2(x,y):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setposition(x,y)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.circle(radius)

Comment: This is the top from turtle import *
setup(500, 500)
Screen()
title("Turtle Keys")
move = Turtle()
showturtle()

Comment: This is the bottom onkey(k1, "Up")
onkey(k2, "Left")
onkey(k3, "Right")
onkey(k4, "Down")

listen()
mainloop()

Comment: Please, please edit your question and format code properly instead of posting small, unreadable code snippets in the comments.

Comment: I apologize for that I am an amateur.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my guess as to what you and your code snippets describe.  Note that I changed the circle and square functions from the left and right keyboard buttons to the left and right mouse buttons which seemed to make more sense in the context of, "move to that location":

```
import turtle
import random

colors = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "violet"]

radius = 10
width = 20

LEFT, MIDDLE, RIGHT = 1, 2, 3

def k1(x=None, y=None):  # dummy arguments so can be a click or key
    turtle.color(random.choice(colors))

def k2(x, y):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setposition(x, y)
    turtle.pendown()
    for _ in range(4):
        turtle.forward(width)
        turtle.right(90)

def k3(x, y):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setposition(x, y)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.circle(radius)

turtle.setup(500, 500)
turtle.Screen().title("Turtle Keys")

turtle.onkey(k1, " ")
turtle.onscreenclick(k2, btn=LEFT)
turtle.onscreenclick(k1, btn=MIDDLE)
turtle.onscreenclick(k3, btn=RIGHT)

turtle.listen()
turtle.mainloop()
```

Comment: I tried running this code but when I press the middle button it draws a circle and doesn't change the color? and when I click the right mouse button nothing happens.

Comment: @myhstery, try it anew and let me know what happens.  Apparently the mouse button mapping doesn't work as documented on my Apple system.  The above is now setup according to how the documentation says it should be.